# waitFor won't run the callback again

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I tried to test what [the documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor) says about waitFor, but when I use a promise the callback won't run again even though it is rejected.

> waitFor may run the callback a variable number of times.
>
> This can be useful if you have a unit test that mocks API calls and
> you need to wait for your mock promises to all resolve.
>
> If you return a promise in the waitFor callback (either explicitly or
> implicitly with async syntax), then the waitFor utility will not call
> your callback again until that promise rejects. This allows you to
> waitFor things that must be checked asynchronously.

```
import { waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import request, { asyncFunc } from "./request";

jest.mock("./request");

function asyncFunc() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      rej(4);
    }, 50);
  });
}

test.only("waits 1 second before ending the game", async () => {
  await waitFor(() => {
    return console.log("heyy"), asyncFunc();
  });
});
```

Comment: @EstusFlask What do you mean wont replicate my problem? I specifically run this code and i get the above problem.

Comment: I mean that other people (not you) may not be able to replicate it. I specifically ran this code and it logged a bunch of `heyy` as it's expected. It's unknown why it would behave like that on your end, could be caused by some dependency versions, or the code differs from what you posted, or else. Since the behaviour is unconventional, the question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to not be offtopic. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Since the problem may be specific to a setup, a repo will suit the case, make sure it really can be reproduced after cloning and installing

Comment: @EstusFlask Could you pls tell me  your testing-library version and jest version

Comment: @testing-library/react 11.1.0 and jest 26.5.3. In my case I obviously don't have "./request" module, which may be the first and very important difference because `function asyncFunc() {` and `{ asyncFunc } from "./request"` compete over the same name and it's not evident which `asyncFunc` implementation is used in `waitFor` in your case.

Comment: @EstusFlask I reproduced what the docs said by applying this "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen" to test react-scripts. I dont know why this wotked. Iam using create-react-app template and all the dependencies are the latest.